# Handle Different Date Formats in Android

Tags: android, date, calendar

Currently using this Library [Calendar Library](https://github.com/prolificinteractive/material-calendarview). The issue I am Facing right now is that Date returned on clicking the dateview in the Calendar is returning date in various formats like 'dd MMM yyyy','MMM dd, yyyy' e.t.c. I need the formatted date as 'yyyy-MM-dd'. How Can I handle this using a simplified way?

Currently I have Handled two scenarios like this but the error is happening in other devices where date format is returned in different formats.

```
   public static String getFormattedDate_event(String normal_date) {
        String anni = normal_date;
        String formated_date = "";
        if (anni.length() > 6) {
            SimpleDateFormat originalFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
            SimpleDateFormat targetFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
            Date date;
            try {
                date = originalFormat.parse(anni);
                formated_date = targetFormat.format(date);
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                //When the Exception is happening trying to parse for another different date format
                if (anni.length() > 6) {
                    SimpleDateFormat originalFormat1 = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd, yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
                    SimpleDateFormat targetFormat1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
                    Date date1;
                    try {
                        date1 = originalFormat1.parse(anni);
                        formated_date = targetFormat1.format(date1);
                    } catch (ParseException e1) {
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    }
                } else {
                    formated_date = anni;
                }
            }
        } else {
            formated_date = anni;
        }
        return formated_date;
    }
```

Calendar Library returning date here

```
 @Override
        public void onDateSelected(@NonNull MaterialCalendarView widget, @NonNull CalendarDay date, boolean selected) {
            selected_date_clicked = EdUtils.getFormattedDate_event(FORMATTER.format(date.getDate()));
            getEventsByDate();
        }
```

Comment: Simple date formats do not recognize the date formats which will be different. You must specify yourself the input date format because some countries represent month before date. Ex: 02 02 2000 so this gets confused like which one in month and which one is days.

Comment: As an aside consider throwing away the long outmoded and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` and friends, and adding [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) to your Android project in order to use `java.time`, the modern Java date and time API. It is so much nicer to work with.